# fork() mysteriously included

Tags: c, linux, gcc, posix

Here is the code (fork.c) that uses fork() to show how it works.

`gcc --version` shows `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int num = 0;
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    int pid;
    pid = fork();       
    if(pid == 0){       /*child*/
        num = 1;
    }else if(pid > 0){  /*parent*/
        num = 2;
    }
    printf("%d", num);
}
```

Then `gcc fork.c -o fork` to compile. It compiles without any error and the executable runs correctly. But I have not included explicitly the header file `unistd.h`, I have also checked all the recursively included header files (`gcc -H`)

```
. /usr/include/stdio.h
.. /usr/include/features.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h
.. /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h
.. /usr/include/libio.h
... /usr/include/_G_config.h
.... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h
.... /usr/include/wchar.h
... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdarg.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio_lim.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sys_errlist.h
```

Then I did `grep` in all the files but I have not found any fork() declaration.

**How could it compile without any error if fork() is never declared in any header file? Or am I missing something?**

Comment: C allows implicit function definitions, it just gets `int fork()` prototype: `int` return value and any number of arguments.  The compiler should emit a warning, though

Comment: Use `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror` to be going on with.  I have more options that I apply before I'm happy with a compilation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In older versions of C (prior to C99: C89 or K&R C) you are not required to have a declaration to call a function. It is then your responsibility to provide correct number and types of arguments, and the return value is assumed to be of type `int`. Compiler does not provide any correctness checking for this case.

Compiler, however, should give you a warning for that. This is what GCC 6.3 gives:

```
main.cpp: In function 'main':
main.cpp:5:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fork' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    pid = fork();
          ^~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Ilya Popov said about declarations, function `fork()` is included in the standard C library, `libc`, which is implicitly linked with the object files when you build your project. This inclusion does not guarantee that the function is called correctly, but it guarantees its presence.