# include library in C is required?

Tags: c, gcc, c11

I'm learnig C, and do some tests.

> Ubuntu 16.01
>
> gcc --version
>
> gcc (GCC) 6.3.0
>   Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

`test.c`

```
main() {
    printf("Hello Word.\n");
    printf("pow function : %f \n", pow(10,2));
}
```

And I use this command to compile:

```
gcc -std=c11  test.c -o test

test.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main() {
 ^~~~
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   printf("Hello Word.\n");
   ^~~~~~
test.c:4:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
test.c:4:3: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
test.c:5:35: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pow’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   printf("powf function : %d \n", pow(10,2));
                                   ^~~
test.c:5:35: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘pow’
test.c:5:35: note: include ‘<math.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘pow’
```

And the end:

```
./test

Hello Word.
pow function : 100.000000
```

ask: Am I required to use `#include <stdio.h>` or any of `C`  [standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)?

---

Change file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello Word.\n");
    printf("powf function : %f \n", pow(10,2));
    return 0;
 }
```

command to compile (this case there are not warnings):

```
gcc -std=c11  test.c -o test
```

Exec output:

```
./test

Hello Word.
pow function : 100.000000
```

In both cases the output was de same.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312198/fork-mysteriously-included

Comment: This is apparently not valid C in multiple aspects. "Hello world" is the first example of **any** C book, so what did you find? Learning C by trial&error only is a very bad idea.

Comment: The warning (`test.c:4:3: warning`) tells you there's an issue, and the very next line(`test.c:4:3:note`) tells you what you need  to do to fix it. The next block (`test.c:5:35:warning' and `test.c:5:35:note`) repeat those same instructions for a different function. Did you **read the words in the message** at all? They're not there just to fill up empty space on your screen; they have information that is very useful, but only if you **actually read** the message to get it.

Comment: I do an update on question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fork() mysteriously included](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312198/fork-mysteriously-included)

Comment: The main problem is not the warnigns. I can use `-w` and the output is de same

Comment: Your first version probably shouldn't have worked -- without including math.h, it would have assumed `pow()` returns `int` and takes whatever you passed it (two `int`s).  With `double` having different internal representation and size, that shouldn't work... but the compiler may have replaced the function call with a constant and made it work anyway (if it didn't replace the call, you'd also have had to link with the math library on many systems, like Linux).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you're calling `printf` and `scanf`, then `#include <stdio.h>` is *mandatory*. Similarly, if you're calling `pow` then `#include <math.h>` is mandatory.

In C90, it was permissible to call a function with no visible declaration. It would be assumed  that the called function returns an `int` result (which is true for `printf` and `scanf`, but not for `pow`) and that its parameters match the arguments you're passing. Calling a *variadic* function, like `printf` or `scanf`, without a visible declaration, or with a declaration that doesn't include the `, ...`, had undefined behavior. This was called the "implicit `int` rule".

C99 dropped that rule. By using `-std=c11`, you're asking the compiler to conform to the C11 standard, which also does not have the implicit `int` rule. In C99 or C11, calling a function without a visible declaration is a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic message from the compiler. (The diagnostic doesn't have to be fatal; the warning you received qualifies.)

One small point: It's legal to provide the declaration yourself rather than using the one provided by the header. There is no good reason to do that.

Also, defining the main function as `main()` is a constraint violation. It should be `int main(void)`.

If you're calling a math function, many implementations also require you to specify that you want to link to the math library, typically by specifying `-lm` at the end of your compiler command line. Others will do so implicitly. You're probably not running into that with your program because the compiler is able to compute `pow(10,2)` at compile time, so it doesn't need the math library. Change one or both of the constants to variables, and the compiler will need to generate an actual call.

C compiler warnings should be taken very seriously. In many cases, compilers will issue non-fatal warnings for things that should, in my humble opinion, be treated as fatal errors.

For gcc, consider using `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 2):

I've this in scratch,plzz **read this carefully**:

In many of our programs, we have used the **library functions printf() & scanf()**.

**Ques.** Where are the prototypes for these?

**Ans.** As well as providing the code for library functions, all standard C implementations provide a set of .h files with this information. The file stdio.h contains the prototypes and macros needed to use the I/O library.

**KeyPoint:**

We have not needed this file before because the compiler will make assumptions about functions if prototypes are not provided. Sometimes these assumptions are ``safe'', but often they are not. It is a good idea, from now on, to include stdio.h in any program using the I/O library.

Answer (score 0):

`pow` function returns a double and you are trying to print it using a `%d` which causes the problem. Refer to man pages of `pow` and also to `format specifiers` for additional details.

Please modify your code as below:

```
printf("powf function : %f \n", pow(10,2));
```

Comment: Thanks for the hit, but the question remains de same.